# Как в c++ создать тип данных "целое число либо одна из констант"

Tags: c++

Есть класс, который позволяет перемещать каретку (нечто вроде сопла 3д принтера) в произвольную позицию:

```
AxesMover am;
am.move({1, 2, 3, 4}); // метод принимает вектор целых чисел - координаты точки
```

Задаётся последовательность движений. Иногда нужно двигать не все координаты. Например:

```
am.move({1, 1, 1, 1});
am.move({1, 1, 1, 2}); // сдвинули только последнюю координату
am.move({2, 2, 1, 2}); // сдвинули первые две
```

Иногда нужно сдвигать не в конкретную позицию, а в максимум для конкретной координаты.

Хотелось бы писать так:

```
am.move({1, DONT_MOVE, 3, MAX}) // не двигать вторую координату, 4 координату в максимум
```

Вижу два варианта

1. Сделать отдельный класс "Позиция". Спец случаи вынести в перечисление:

```
enum class SpecialPos {
    DONT_MOVE,
    MIN,
    MAX
}
    
сlass Positions {
      public:
        Position(unsigned long n) : _coordinate(n), special(false),
            _sp(SpecialPos::DONT_MOVE) { }
    
        Position(SpecialPos sp) : _coordinate(0), special(true), _sp(sp) { }
    
        bool operator==(Positions const & rhs) const { 
          if (_special) return _sp == rhs._sp;
          else return _coordinate == rhs._coordinate;
        }
    private:
        unsigned long const _coordinate;
    
        bool const _special;
        
        SpecialPos const _sp;
}
```

В таком варианте не очень нравится использование констант: SpecialPos::DONT_MOVE
Да и доп приватные поля сомнительно смотрятся

2. Спец случаями считать числа вида MAX_LONG - n (MAX_LONG: не двигать, MAX_LONG - 1: минимум и т.д.)

В таком варианте не нравится интерфейс (нужно будет в комментариях описывать, что эти числа отведены под спецслучаи)

Больше склоняюсь к первому варианту. Есть альтернативные предложения?

Comment: Может задавать вместо `DONT_MOVE` текущую координату, а вместо `MAX` - максимальную?

Comment: @user7860670 Вот как раз чтобы не дублировать предыдущую координату и думаю добавить эти константы)

Comment: ¿А почему это вызывает затруднение?

Comment: @user7860670 Не то чтобы затруднение - дублирование. Ну и неочевидно, что автор хотел оставить координату на месте

Comment: ¿Что именно дублируется и как при записи вида `current_pos.x` может быть не очевидно, что автор хотел оставить координату на месте?

Comment: @user7860670 Нет текущей позиции - есть следующая. Движение до неё осуществляется в несколько вызовов:

`move({2, 1, 1}); move({2, 2, 1}); move({2, 2, 2});`

Comment: Мне представляется, что если начать отслеживать текущую позицию, то должно упроститься.

Comment: @user7860670 Может быть. Попробую и отпишусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно использовать [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), который является типобезопасной альтернативой union, и как раз и предназначен, чтобы держать значение одного из нескольких типов. При этом специальные значения можно поместить в enum:

```
#include <variant>

enum class SpecialPosition
{
    DONT_MOVE,
    MIN,
    MAX
};

using Position = std::variant<unsigned long, SpecialPosition>;
```

Пользоваться так:

```
void move(std::array<Position, 4> positions)
{
    for (auto& p : positions)
    {
        if (std::holds_alternative<unsigned long>(p))
        {
            std::cout << "Moving to position " << std::get<unsigned long>(p) << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (std::get<SpecialPosition>(p))
            {
            case SpecialPosition::DONT_MOVE:
                std::cout << "Not moving" << std::endl;
                break;
            case SpecialPosition::MIN:
                std::cout << "Moving to min" << std::endl;
                break;
            case SpecialPosition::MAX:
                std::cout << "Moving to max" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    move({ 1ul, SpecialPosition::DONT_MOVE, 2ul, SpecialPosition::MAX });
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт:

> ```
> Moving to position 1
> Not moving
> Moving to position 2
> Moving to max
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант с сохранением текущей позиции:

```
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

using
t_Pos = ::std::array<int, 3>;

class
t_AxesMover
{
    public: void
    move(t_Pos const pos)
    {
        ::std::cout << "moving to " <<
            pos[0] << " " << pos[1] << " " << pos[2] <<
            ::std::endl;
        return;
    }
};

class
t_MoveHelper
{
    private: t_AxesMover & m_mover;
    private: t_Pos m_pos;

    public: explicit
    t_MoveHelper(t_AxesMover & mover) noexcept
    :   m_mover{mover}
    ,   m_pos{}
    {
        return;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    operator ()(void)
    {
        m_mover.move(m_pos);
        return *this;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    operator ()(t_Pos const pos)
    {
        m_pos = pos;
        m_mover.move(m_pos);
        return *this;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    x(int const value) noexcept
    {
        m_pos[0] = value;
        return *this;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    xmax(void) noexcept
    {
        return x(::std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    y(int const value) noexcept
    {
        m_pos[1] = value;
        return *this;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    ymax(void) noexcept
    {
        return y(::std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    z(int const value) noexcept
    {
        m_pos[2] = value;
        return *this;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    zmax(void) noexcept
    {
        return z(::std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    }
};

int main()
{
    t_AxesMover mover{};
    t_MoveHelper helper{mover};
    helper
    // двигаем по всем координатам, передавая объект координаты
    (t_Pos{1, 1, 1})
    // двигаем по всем координатам, задавая координаты в любом порядке
    .y(3).x(2).z(4)()
    // двигаем только по x и z
    .x(5).z(7)()
    // двигаем по y до упора
    .ymax()();
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vv65Ejdab

Comment: Выглядит неплохо) Не отвечает на вопрос непосредственно, но, думаю, будет удобно в использовании

Answer (score 1):

Эзотерический пятничный вариант с FORTH-style командами:

```
helper,
// двигаем по всем координатам, передавая объект координаты
t_Pos{1, 1, 1},
// двигаем по всем координатам, задавая координаты в любом порядке
3, y, 2, x, 4, z, move,
// двигаем только по x и z
5, x, 7, z, move,
// двигаем по y до упора
max, y, move;
```

код:

```
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using
t_Pos = ::std::array<int, 3>;

class
t_AxesMover
{
    public: void
    Move(t_Pos const pos)
    {
        ::std::cout << "moving to " <<
            pos[0] << " " << pos[1] << " " << pos[2] <<
            ::std::endl;
        return;
    }
};

struct
t_Flusher final
{
    // ничего...
};

struct
t_Max final
{
    // ничего...
};

struct
t_Axis final
{
    ::std::size_t const index;
};

class
t_MoveHelper final
{
    private: t_AxesMover & m_mover;
    private: t_Pos m_pos;

    public: explicit
    t_MoveHelper(t_AxesMover & mover) noexcept
    :   m_mover{mover}
    ,   m_pos{}
    {
        return;
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    operator ,([[maybe_unused]] t_Flusher const & dummy) noexcept
    {
        m_mover.Move(m_pos);
        return *this;
    }

    private: class
    t_ValueApply final
    {
        private: t_MoveHelper & m_helper;
        private: int const m_value;

        public: explicit constexpr
        t_ValueApply(t_MoveHelper & helper, int const value) noexcept
        :   m_helper{helper}
        ,   m_value{value}
        {
            return;
        }

        public: t_MoveHelper &
        operator ,(t_Axis const axis) const && noexcept
        {
            m_helper.m_pos[axis.index] = m_value;
            return m_helper;
        }
    };

    public: t_ValueApply
    operator ,([[maybe_unused]] t_Max const & dummy) noexcept
    {
        return t_ValueApply(*this, ::std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
    }

    public: t_ValueApply
    operator ,(int const value) noexcept
    {
        return t_ValueApply(*this, value);
    }

    public: t_MoveHelper &
    operator ,(t_Pos const pos) noexcept
    {
        m_pos = pos;
        m_mover.Move(m_pos);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr t_Flusher const move{};
    constexpr t_Max const max{};
    constexpr t_Axis const x{0};
    constexpr t_Axis const y{1};
    constexpr t_Axis const z{2};

    t_AxesMover mover{};
    t_MoveHelper helper{mover};

    helper,
    // двигаем по всем координатам, передавая объект координаты
    t_Pos{1, 1, 1},
    // двигаем по всем координатам, задавая координаты отдельно, в любом порядке
    3, y, 2, x, 4, z, move,
    // двигаем только по x и z
    5, x, 7, z, move,
    // двигаем по y до упора
    max, y, move;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nbdx348aK

Comment: Вариант уж больно эзотерический. Поэтому определённо + :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov На самом деле это скорее самый распространённый вариант, реализованный в postscript и подобных протоколах. В т.ч. и для 3д принтеров. Компактно, удобно и без оверхеда, хотя в С++ такой подход - редкость.

Comment: Я именно с точки зрения плюсов и говорю ;)

Answer (score -4):

1 вариант) сделать как всегда это делается:

```
enum class SpecialPos {
    DONT_MOVE = 12341,
    MIN,
    MAX
}
```

и

```
if(val>=DONT_MOVE)
```

2 вариант) сделать как надо:

```
enum class SpecialPos {
    DONT_MOVE,
    MIN,
    MAX
}

variant<int, SpecialPos> val
```

И долго потом пытаться что-то с этим написать.

Первый вариант если нужно чтобы работало, а второй чтобы было веселее кодить, visit там побзать например.

> (нужно будет в комментариях описывать, что эти числа отведены под спецслучаи)

Ну так и делается. Написать такой коммент самая меньшая из проблем в C++.

Comment: "сделать как всегда это делается" - что за трешовый совет...

Comment: 1 вариант не работает - enum class не конвертируется в int по-умолчанию (как раз для этого его и использую). К тому же, он обязывает пользователя учитывать, что эта константа не может быть использована в качестве координаты.

2 вариант интересный, но код для ардуинки, а на ней 14-е плюсы).

Комментарий действительно просто написать, но использовать и сопровождать код станет чуть сложнее

Comment: Ну кто ж такие константы ставит. :( Вы бы хоть в край диапазона инта их поставили.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в край диапазона ставить тоже негоже: изначальная проблема никуда не уходит, пусть и в магических числах появляется хоть минимальная логика